# SQL Developer explain plan broken

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-execution-plan

Trying to generate an explain plan in SQL Developer, the program puts up a message box with title "failed to query plan_table" complaining "invalid column name". The plan is not generated or displayed. How to fix?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Execute this sql statement:

```
drop table plan_table
```

SQL Developer automatically regenerated the proper table & displayed the correct plan after pressing F6 again.

Answer (score 8):

Normally PLAN_TABLE is a public synonym pointing to a table owned by SYS (e.g. SYS.PLAN_TABLE$ in 11g.)

If you have recently upgraded the database, the plan_table is likely still "old" and needs to be upgraded (by the dba)

Each user should not have to worry about creating their own plan_table.

Comment: +1... additionally, be sure the ?/rdbms/admin/catplan.sql script is used to create the new version as a global temporary table, which offers some isolation advantages.